# Polymer 2.x: ES6 Class-based Syntax, element definition

Tags: polymer, es6-class, es6-modules, polymer-2.x

[In the preview documentation here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/tree/2.0-preview#20-es6-class-based-syntax), there is the following bit of code:

```
class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'my-element' }
```

My question is: Does the `MyElement` bit in the first line have to match the `my-element` bit in the second line? Is the first bit constrained by the second in any way? Or vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the classname has no bearing on the element name that you return from the `is` getter. For example, the class could be named `XFoo` and the element name `my-app`:

```
class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'my-app'; }
}

customElements.define(XFoo.is, XFoo);
```

The class could also be anonymous:

```
customElements.define('my-app', class extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'my-app'; }
});
```

`customElement.define()` is defined in the [Web Components Custom Elements spec](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/), which might be why it's not explained in the Polymer 2.0-preview Wiki. The spec does not impose any stipulations on the classname. From examples in the spec and in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements/Custom_Elements_with_Classes), the classname usually at least resembles the element name (likely for maintainability).

- **MDN instance:** `save-button` vs `SaveBtn`:

  ```
  var MySaveBtn = document.registerElement("save-button", SaveBtn);
  ```
- **Custom Elements Spec instance:** `auto-embiggened` vs `AutoEmbiggenedImage`:

  ```
  customElements.define("auto-embiggened", AutoEmbiggenedImage, { extends: "img" });
  ```

Comment: Can you point to any good documentation that describes how all this works? The Polymer docs I referenced to not explain that.

Comment: Added links to Custom Elements spec. See updated answer.